# Synopsys Coverity configuration with Azure DevOps Pipeline (Linux Agent)

Tags: azure-devops, devops, coverity

I am new to working with Azure DevOps. I am trying to create a pipeline using Azure DevOps for Build a Linux project. In the pipeline I added Synopsys Coverity task for Coverity analysis. I also installed Coverity in my self hosted agent. I use the below settings for the Coverity task

[image]

But I am getting the below error

> Looking for translation units
>   Error: intermediate directory contains no translation units.
>   An error occured: The process '/home/platform/cov-analysis-linux64-2019.12/bin/cov-analyze' failed with exit code 2

Comment: What's the result if you run the related commands locally in your dev machine? And could you share some details about your project so that we can reproduce the issue?